# Not able to match input with expected result

Tags: vb.net, random

I'm making a Visual Basic program for a game called Mastermind, where there are a certain number of pins (defined by the user) and a number of color options for each pin (also defined by the user). The user tries to guess a randomly generated "code" by selecting the color for each pin, and the system tells you how many pins you got correct, and how many colors you got correct, but on the wrong pin.

The issue is, when I search my array and tell it to display the number of correct pins, it always displays either 1 or 0, even when I set it to only one color option (meaning I should get all of them right by default). Here is my code (yes I know the ColorsCorrect function is empty, but that one isn't concerned here):

```
 Imports System.Drawing.Color
Public Class Form1
    Dim intNumbOfPegs As Integer = 0
    Dim intNumbOfColors As Integer = 0
    Dim intPegsGenned As Integer = 0
    Dim intColorsGenned As Integer = 0
    Dim intColorsToGuess(-1) As Integer
    Dim intColorsGuessed(-1) As Integer
    Dim GroupBox(-1) As GroupBox
    Dim RadioButton(-1, -1) As RadioButton
    Dim blnGenNewNumbs As Boolean = True

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Do
            intNumbOfPegs = InputBox("Enter The Number of Pegs (1 - 10):", "Number of Pegs")
            intNumbOfColors = InputBox("Enter The Number of Colors (1 - 9):", "Number of Colors")
            If intNumbOfColors = 0 Or intNumbOfColors > 9 Or intNumbOfPegs = 0 Or intNumbOfPegs > 10 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input. Please Try Again", "Error")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("You Have Selected " & intNumbOfPegs & " Pegs and " & intNumbOfColors & " Colors")
            End If
        Loop While intNumbOfColors = 0 Or intNumbOfColors > 9 Or intNumbOfPegs = 0 Or intNumbOfPegs > 10
        ReDim intColorsGuessed(intNumbOfPegs - 1)
        ReDim intColorsToGuess(intNumbOfPegs - 1)
        ReDim GroupBox(intNumbOfPegs - 1)
        ReDim RadioButton(intNumbOfColors - 1, intNumbOfPegs - 1)
        Do While intPegsGenned < intNumbOfPegs
            intPegsGenned = intPegsGenned + 1
            GroupBox(intPegsGenned - 1) = New GroupBox
            GroupBox(intPegsGenned - 1).Name = "grpPeg" & intPegsGenned
            GroupBox(intPegsGenned - 1).Text = "Peg " & intPegsGenned
            GroupBox(intPegsGenned - 1).Size = New System.Drawing.Size(64, 238)
            GroupBox(intPegsGenned - 1).Location = New System.Drawing.Point(59 + (70 * intPegsGenned), 12)
            Do While intColorsGenned < intNumbOfColors
                intColorsGenned = intColorsGenned + 1
                RadioButton(intColorsGenned - 1, intPegsGenned - 1) = New RadioButton
                RadioButton(intColorsGenned - 1, intPegsGenned - 1).Size = New System.Drawing.Size(31, 17)
                RadioButton(intColorsGenned - 1, intPegsGenned - 1).Name = "radPeg" & intPegsGenned & "Color" & intColorsGenned
                RadioButton(intColorsGenned - 1, intPegsGenned - 1).Text = intColorsGenned
                RadioButton(intColorsGenned - 1, intPegsGenned - 1).Location = New System.Drawing.Point(17, 6 + (23 * intColorsGenned))
                'AddHandler RadioButton(intColorsGenned - 1).CheckedChanged, AddressOf AllRadButtons_CheckedChanged
                GroupBox(intPegsGenned - 1).Controls.Add(RadioButton(intColorsGenned - 1, intPegsGenned - 1))
            Loop
            intColorsGenned = 0
            Controls.Add(GroupBox(intPegsGenned - 1))
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCheckGuess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheckGuess.Click
        Dim intColorToCheck As Integer = 0
        Dim intPegToCheck As Integer = 0

        If blnGenNewNumbs = True Then
            ChooseColors()
            blnGenNewNumbs = False
        End If

        Do While intPegToCheck < intNumbOfPegs
            Do While intColorToCheck < intNumbOfColors
                If RadioButton(intColorToCheck, intPegToCheck).Checked = True Then
                    intColorsGuessed(intPegToCheck) = intColorToCheck + 1
                End If
                intColorToCheck = intColorToCheck + 1
            Loop
            intPegToCheck = intPegToCheck + 1
        Loop

        lblGuessDisplay.Text = lblGuessDisplay.Text & " Correct Pegs: " & PegsCorrect() & " Correct Colors: " & ColorsCorrect()

    End Sub

    Sub ChooseColors()
        Dim intNumbsFilled As Integer = 0
        Do While intNumbsFilled < intNumbOfPegs
            intColorsToGuess(intNumbsFilled) = RndInt()
            intNumbsFilled = intNumbsFilled + 1
        Loop
    End Sub
    Function RndInt()
        Dim intNumbToSend As Integer = 0
        Randomize()
        intNumbToSend = (Int(intNumbOfColors * Rnd()) + 1)
        Return intNumbToSend
    End Function

    Function PegsCorrect() As Integer
        Dim intPegsCorrect As Integer = 0
        Dim intPegCorrectToCheck As Integer = 0

        Do While intPegCorrectToCheck <= (intNumbOfPegs - 1)
            If intColorsToGuess(intPegCorrectToCheck) = intColorsGuessed(intPegCorrectToCheck) Then
                intPegsCorrect = intPegsCorrect + 1
            End If
            intPegCorrectToCheck = intPegCorrectToCheck + 1
        Loop
        Return intPegsCorrect
    End Function

    Function ColorsCorrect() As Integer
        Dim intColorsCorrect As Integer = 0

        Return intColorsCorrect
    End Function

End Class
```

Why is it not working as intended?

Comment: Gah, this brings back nightmares from VB6. You can still write VB.Net this way, but it's not very idiomatic anymore. For example, modern VB.Net rarely uses the "Loop" or "ReDim" keywords.

Comment: Check out the .net Random class. Much easier to use. Also check out List(Of T), It would save you worrying about the size of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to enable [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement). That will point out some problems, but not enough to make it work.

Next, those While loops are begging to be changed to For..Next loops. I may or may not have corrected an off-by-one error or two when I did that to see if I could fix it. Some variable renaming was in order - there is no point having nigh on everything preceded by "int". Some variables had too wide a scope too.

With the code cleaned up a bit, it is now easier to debug it and discover that the `RndInt()` function isn't behaving as you might hope - banker's rounding is not what is needed there; instead you need:

```
Function RndInt() As Integer
    Return CInt(Math.Truncate(nColours * Rnd())) + 1

End Function
```

---

For what it's worth, this is where I ended up getting it to work:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim nPegs As Integer = 0
    Dim nColours As Integer = 0

    Dim hiddenColours(-1) As Integer
    Dim userGuesses(-1) As Integer

    Dim GroupBox(-1) As GroupBox
    Dim RadioButton(-1, -1) As RadioButton

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim inputsValid As Boolean
        Do
            nPegs = CInt(InputBox("Enter The Number of Pegs (1 - 10):", "Number of Pegs"))
            nColours = CInt(InputBox("Enter The Number of Colors (1 - 9):", "Number of Colors"))
            inputsValid = nColours >= 1 AndAlso nColours <= 9 AndAlso nPegs >= 1 AndAlso nPegs <= 9

            If inputsValid Then
                MessageBox.Show("You Have Selected " & nPegs & " Pegs and " & nColours & " Colors")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input. Please Try Again", "Error")
            End If

        Loop While Not inputsValid

        ReDim userGuesses(nPegs - 1)
        ReDim hiddenColours(nPegs - 1)
        ReDim GroupBox(nPegs - 1)
        ReDim RadioButton(nColours - 1, nPegs - 1)

        Randomize()
        ChooseColors()

        For pegNumber = 0 To nPegs - 1
            GroupBox(pegNumber) = New GroupBox
            GroupBox(pegNumber).Name = "grpPeg" & pegNumber
            GroupBox(pegNumber).Text = "Peg " & (pegNumber + 1)
            GroupBox(pegNumber).Size = New System.Drawing.Size(64, 238)
            GroupBox(pegNumber).Location = New System.Drawing.Point(59 + (70 * pegNumber), 12)

            For colourNumber = 0 To nColours - 1
                Dim rb As New RadioButton
                rb.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(31, 17)
                rb.Name = "radPeg" & pegNumber & "Color" & colourNumber
                rb.Text = (colourNumber + 1).ToString()
                rb.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(17, 29 + 23 * colourNumber)

                RadioButton(colourNumber, pegNumber) = rb
                GroupBox(pegNumber).Controls.Add(RadioButton(colourNumber, pegNumber))

            Next

            Me.Controls.Add(GroupBox(pegNumber))

        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCheckGuess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheckGuess.Click
        For peg = 0 To nPegs - 1
            For colourNum = 0 To nColours - 1
                If RadioButton(colourNum, peg).Checked Then
                    userGuesses(peg) = colourNum + 1
                End If
            Next
        Next

        lblGuessDisplay.Text = " Correct Pegs: " & PegsCorrect() & " Correct Colors: " & ColorsCorrect()

    End Sub

    Sub ChooseColors()
        For i = 0 To nPegs - 1
            hiddenColours(i) = RndInt()
        Next

    End Sub

    Function RndInt() As Integer
        Return CInt(Math.Truncate(nColours * Rnd())) + 1

    End Function

    Function PegsCorrect() As Integer
        Dim nCorrect As Integer = 0

        For i = 0 To nPegs - 1
            If hiddenColours(i) = userGuesses(i) Then
                nCorrect += 1
            End If
        Next

        Return nCorrect

    End Function

    Function ColorsCorrect() As Integer
        Dim intColorsCorrect As Integer = 0

        Return intColorsCorrect

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks! Was there any one specific problem with my code, or was it just several little issues?

Comment: @IanFinnigan I suspect it was only the random number generation which was he problem - you could just replace the body of the function in your code with what I showed and test. But I tidied up the code first to make it easier for me to find where it was going wrong, so it *might* be that there were other problems that were accidentally fixed in the process - I kept testing as I changed small pieces and it may have *looked* like I had made a correction when in fact it was the random numbers that made it look better.

Comment: it looks like there were some other problems you fixed while cleaning it up. Anywat, it works now